# Source style for Google Code Jam

Tags: input

I plan on doing the Code Jam competition next year. The problem is (something that I can't find anywhere) how do I set up my code to accept input and return an output?

I'm just confused as to how I am supposed to handle everything, say for example that I have to add **1** to the input and make the result the output, how would I handle the input/output?

I plan on using LUA. Thanks if you can. I think a code example would be best!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to http://www.go-hero.net/jam/11/solutions and choose the problem and the language. You'll find all the examples you need there. Including Lua ones.

Comment: Links are dead :(

Comment: May have been a temporary glitch. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Can you get to individual solutions? eg https://www.go-hero.net/jam/11/name/AllenS

Comment: Also, thanks for fast response on post that is almost 10 years old. :)

Answer (score 6):

http://www.go-hero.net/jam/
On this page you can see source code for every contestant.
You should be able to answer your question from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can either do I/O on files or on stdin/stdout. It doesn't matter. I've seen examples that used files and examples that used stdin/stdout.

Comment: Could you give me a code example of this by any chance?  I am hopelessly lost =/

Comment: If you don't know how to print hello world to the console, it's unlikely that you'll pass the qualification round.

Comment: Well in that case, you don't get points.  Somebody else was able to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

In Python say, you could write

```
import fileinput
f = fileinput.input()
```

Then call the script from the shell like this

```
gorosort.py A-small-practice.in
```

To save the output to a file

```
gorosort.py A-small-practice.in > A-small-practice.out
```